# Failed to Fetch Error while calling Azure Function

Tags: spfx, api, azure-functions, post

I am calling an Azure Function which is publicly accessible from my SPFx web part.

It is a POST Request and I am getting a Failed to Fetch error.

The same API call is working fine if I execute it from POSTMAN.

Below is the code.

```
fetch(checkSubscriptionURL, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ "TenantID": tenantId }),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
          }
        }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (res.status !== 200) {
            reject();
          }
          else {
            res.json().then(data => {
              if (data && data.length > 0) {
                resolve(this.parseSubscription(data[0]));
              }
              else {
                reject();
              }
            })
          }
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          reject();
        })
```

Can anyone please help with this?

I tried to make the call with SPFxHTTPClient but getting the same error with that as well.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to resolve it ? I am getting same error but with PnPJs in SPFx Webpart

Comment: @zainul please check the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @zainul  If the answer helped you resolve your error. Kindly upvote it. So it will help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by setting the value of CORS in the Azure Function API Settings.

This is not available in the New Experience. We can access it from the classic/old view of azure function.

**Steps:**

1. Go To the Azure Function.
2. Switch to classic view.
3. Click on Platform Features.
4. Under the API section, click on CORS.
5. Under Allowed origins add your domain URL.

[image]